# How to make an Active X (control) stay 'enabled'?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I am using internet explorer version 8 with Windows XP.
If you go to
Tools> Manage Add-ons > Toolbars & Extensions,
you see: name, publisher, status. 
Under status it's either 'enabled' or 'unabled.'

My problem is, 
one of it (which is Active X control) is unabled, so I changed it to enabled. But onto the next web page, it's again changed back to unabled.

How can I make it stay 'enabled'? :'(